# Android Collection.sort inconsistently crashes based on Android API Version

Tags: java, android

An interesting bug that essentially if you have this line of code in your Android code it crashes on Android API 21 but works on API 28

```
Collections.sort(Collections.singletonList(“1”));


java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.AbstractList.set(AbstractList.java:681)
at java.util.AbstractList$FullListIterator.set(AbstractList.java:143)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1869)
at com.davidcorrado.collectionssort.CollectionJavaUnitTest2.Collection_Sort_Immutable(CollectionJavaUnitTest2.java:16)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
```

I understand why it crashes as it does not allow immutable objects in Collection.sort but I really do not understand the inconsistency.

I have this code example:
https://github.com/DavidCorrado/CollectionSortCrash/blob/master/app/src/androidTest/java/com/davidcorrado/collectionssort/CollectionJavaUnitTest2.java

So if you run the above test targeting API 21 emulator it crashes but on API 28 emulator it works.  This also applies to real devices.

So I have 2 questions

1) What in different in these devices that I do not know about that causes this.

2) Is there a way to get this error in robo electric.  I have a code example that succeeds.

Comment: Different particular implementations of sorting might or might not try to move elements around.  It's perfectly reasonable that the implementation of sorting might change from version to version.

Comment: Do you know what causes the implementation to be different depending on API version.  Like is there some documentation of why different API versions have different code.  I am just trying to wrap my head around it.  Where all does Android pull code from that differs on API version.

Comment: Why?  Because they figured out a way to sort more efficiently, that happens to do different operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with API 28 because the implementation of sort was replaced, and the new version has optimization that simply skips the sorting if `list.size() <= 1`.

When sorting is skipped, it doesn't calls `list.set()`, and hence never triggers the `UnsupportedOperationException` of an immutable list.

Older API levels don't have that optimization.

Comment: Interesting.   Seems like this is true.  Do you know where this optimization exists in their code?  Do you have an article where it explains what code is run on different API versions?  Is it JVM related?

Comment: @DavidCorrado Sorry, I don't have any specifics, though I do know that they [replaced the sorting algorithm in Java 7 to use TimSort](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47084824/5221149).